# Открыть pdf в окне браузера (ajax)

Tags: javascript, ajax, pdf, header

Есть запрос при выполнении которого сервер отдает pdf файл. проблема в том что в тело запроса нужно прикрутить header, результат запроса отобразить в новом окне, ну или хотя бы инициировать загрузку

```
        $.ajax({
            url: 'url',
            type: 'GET',
            headers: {
                'token': token

            },
            success: function (data) {
                var blob = new Blob([data]);
                var link = document.createElement('a');
                link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                window.open(link);
            }
        });
```

На выходе получаю страницу с таким текстом

```
%PDF-1.4
%пїЅпїЅпїЅпїЅ
4 0 obj
>stream
xпїЅНќНЏ$WVпїЅCпїЅ]!!пїЅпїЅпїЅпїЅпїЅпїЅrпїЅ=пїЅпїЅпїЅпїЅxпїЅEFпїЅМ¬PпїЅпЂпїЅ?0 ,пїЅ
```

если убрать на сервере проверку token, прямой переход по url, выдает нужный pdf документ.

Comment: Пусть вам сервер по ajax возвращает ссылку на pdf документ, а вы уже его открывайте в браузере: в новом окне, во фрейме или в замен текущей страницы.

Comment: сам pdf на сервере не хранится. при обращении к серверу генерируется из базы и отдается потоком

Comment: Ссылку отдавайте на файл, который и будет генерировать вам нужный pdf.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   $('.test').click(function () {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('GET', 'http://localhost:8080/export?from=01.01.2014&to=01.01.2016', true);
        xhr.responseType = 'blob';
        xhr.setRequestHeader("token", "token");
        xhr.onload = function (e) {
            if (this.status == 200) {

                var blob = new Blob([this.response], {type: 'application/pdf'}),
                        url = URL.createObjectURL(blob)

                window.open(url);
            }
        };
        xhr.send();
    });
```

открывает новую страницу с нужным pdf. еще бы отредактировать отображаемый пользователю url(следовательно и имя документа)

Answer (score 1):

Занимаюсь тем же самым. Мой вариант кода ниже, но я так же на выходе получаю только одностраничный пустой pdf, хотя если делать прямой GET запрос, то pdf генерируется как и должен

```js
.done(function(data, status, xhr) {
  var disposition = xhr.getResponseHeader('Content-Disposition');
  if(disposition && disposition.search('attachment') != -1){
    // check for a filename
    var filename = "";
    var filenameRegex = /filename[^;=\n]*=((['"]).*?\2|[^;\n]*)/;
    var matches = filenameRegex.exec(disposition);
    if (matches != null && matches[1]) filename = matches[1].replace(/['"]/g, '');

    var type = xhr.getResponseHeader('Content-Type');

    var blob = new Blob([data], {type: type});

    if (typeof window.navigator.msSaveBlob !== 'undefined') {
      // IE workaround for "HTML7007: One or more blob URLs were revoked by closing the blob for which they were created. These URLs will no longer resolve as the data backing the URL has been freed."
      window.navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, filename);
    } else {
      var URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
      var downloadUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

      if (filename) {
        // use HTML5 a[download] attribute to specify filename
        var a = document.createElement("a");
        // safari doesn't support this yet
        if (typeof a.download === 'undefined') {
          window.location = downloadUrl;
        } else {
          a.href = downloadUrl;
          a.download = filename;
          document.body.appendChild(a);
          a.click();
        }
      } else {
        window.location = downloadUrl;
      }
      setTimeout(function () {
        URL.revokeObjectURL(downloadUrl);
      }, 100); // cleanup
    }
  }
```

Comment: Копаю дальше http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21950828/how-to-display-a-server-side-generated-pdf-stream-in-javascript-sent-via-httpmes но и тут пока нет решения